# Problem using optiontohead in scrreprt class

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, classicthesis

I am using `claasicthesis` version `v4.1` along with `scrreprt` version `v3.11b`. I am trying to force printing the longer version of the section title in the table of content but no success so far.

I used the following options for `scrreprt`:

```
\documentclass[ 
            openright,
            titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,
            footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
            BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, 
            dottedtoc, 
            ngerman, american, 
            headings=optiontohead,
            ]{scrreprt}
```

and also the following for `classicthesis`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
                eulerchapternumbers,
                listings,
                pdfspacing,
                subfig,
                beramono,                  
                parts}{classicthesis}
```

In the manual it is mentioned that:

> `\section[short version ]{heading }`
>
> with option `headings=optiontohead`, KOMA -Script doesn’t use the
>   optional argument short version at the table of contents, but for the running head only.

Unfortunately, for some reason the table of content still uses the short version of the title even after using `headings=optiontohead`. Could someone please let me know how I force `scrreprt` to use the longer version of the section title in TOC?

Comment: After chatting with @egreg, he suggested me to avoid using long titles in `classicthesis`. "`classicthesis` uses `titlesec` that disrupts the method used by `scrbook` for the `headings=...` option.", said egreg.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a similar [question on the GuIT forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/89657-testatine-e-arsclassica?lang=en#89678)

> The problem is quite intricated. Since `classicthesis` uses `titlesec`, the method `scrbook` uses for deciding what goes in the header or in the table of contents with `headings=optiontohead` doesn't work.
>
> I fear that the only way is to say
>
> ```
> \stepcounter{section}
> \sectionmark{Azione collettiva o scelta individuale}
> \addtocounter{section}{-1}
> \section{La ristrutturazione: un problema di azione collettiva
>   o una razionale scelta individuale?}
> \sectionmark{Azione collettiva o scelta individuale}
> ```
>
> The best would be avoiding long titles.